# Differentation under the integral sign

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Let *I* be an open subinterval of $\mathbb R$ and let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a Borel measurable function such that $x \to e^{tx}f(x)$ is Lebesgue integrable for each *t* in *I*. Define $h: I \to \mathbb R$ by $h(t)= \int_\mathbb R e^{tx}f(x)\lambda(dx)$. Show that *h* is differentiable, with derivative given by $h'(t)=\int_\mathbb R xe^{tx}f(x)\lambda(dx)$, at each *t* in *I*. Of course, it is part of your task to shat that $x \to xe^{tx}f(x)$ is integrable for each *t* in *I*.

My idea is to show using the MacLaurin expansion of $e^u$ that $\lvert e^u-1 \rvert \lt \lvert u \rvert e^{\lvert u \rvert}$ holds for each *u* in $\mathbb R$ and after use the Monotone Convergence Theorem but I'm a bit stuck. Can you help me?

Comment: What is $\lambda(x)$?

Comment: @TonyK sorry it was $\lambda (dx)$

Comment: This is Exercise 2.4.10 in Donald L. Cohn, *Measure Theory* (second edition 2013). The part dishonestly described as "my idea" is actually the hint provided by the author! It has been slightly rewritten to disguise this fact. I have downvoted the question because not only is it a textbook example (pardon the pun) of a "Problem Statement Question", but a deliberate attempt has been made to disguise this fact, and to pretend that the OP has done some work on it.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(t_n)$ be a sequence converging to a point $t \in I = (a,b)$, and define

$$g_n(x,t) = \frac{e^{t_n x}f(x)-e^{tx}f(x)}{t_n-t}.$$

The sequence converges to the partial derivative with respect to t, which as a limit of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}g_n(x,t) = xe^{tx}f(x).$$

By the mean value theorem, there is a point $\xi_n$ between $t$ and $t_n$ such that

$$|g_n(x,t)| = e^{\xi_n x}f(x) \leqslant \max(e^{ax},e^{bx})f(x) = g(x).$$

Since $g$ is integrable we can apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem to show

$$h'(t) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{h(t_n)-h(t)}{t_n-t} \\ = \lim_{n \to \infty}\int g_n(x,t) \lambda(dx)\\ = \int \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x,t) \lambda(dx) \\= \int xe^{tx}f(x) \lambda(dx)$$

Comment: Application of the M.V.T to $e^{t x}f(x)$ should yield $x e^{\xi_n x}f(x)$ if I'm not mistaken, not $e^{\xi_n x}f(x)$

Comment: You did not cover the case where the open subinterval is unbounded, though.

Comment: @meth-  How would that be different? Differentiability of $h$ is a local property.  Take any $t \in \mathbb{R}$  and any bounded interval $I$ containing $t$.  The above argument proves that $h$ is differentiable at $t$ and the derivative can be obtained by differentiating under the integral.